# Clojure excel interaction (formulas)

Tags: excel, apache, clojure, apache-poi

I'm looking for a clojure library that can easily read and write to excel with the following features:

- needs to be compatible with .xlsx
- reading: needs to be able to evaluate a formula before returning a value
- writing: needs to append rows to end of a sheet easily
- (optional) cell formatting: bold, highlight, center-align, etc.

I've checked out clojars and tried to use incanter-excel, which seems to be able to do all of that, but it uses a lot of excess stuff like reading into a Dataset type and GUI displays. I'd prefer something that just uses the native structures in clojure (lists, vectors, etc.), because I'm really just taking a bunch of strings that I pull from different places and plopping them into cells (every row will have the same number of fields).

```
(ns incanterTest.core)
(use '(incanter core excel))
(let [data (read-xls "test.xlsx")]
  (type data)
  (view data))
```

test.xlsx:

```
n   m   n+m
1   2   3     <- =A2+B2
10  20  30    <- =A3+B3
```

I'd like to use clojure-esque syntax, but perhaps using APACHE POI directly is easiest? Thanks for your help

Comment: Look for a Clojure wrapper to Apache POI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [docjure](https://github.com/ative/docjure) by Martin Jul. Not entirely sure what you mean by your second bullet though.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not what you want, but cool ... eh ... evil nonetheless: [spreadmap](https://github.com/cgrand/spreadmap).

Answer (score 1):

another way is to check out http://github.com/tuddman/clj-dde   which can easily read & write to & from excel

can also use to have dynamic 'listeners' on any cell(s) if you want to read out results from excel-defined formulas.